# GeoPandas - GeoData not overlapping Shapefile map

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, gis, shapefile, geopandas

I'm trying to map some lat/long data transformed into shapely.geometry.Point objects from a geopandas.GeoDataFrame onto a UK shapefile downloaded from [here](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2/gis-files/great-britain-shapefile). Upon extraction there are 3 .shp files and the problem below occurs with each of them.

Following is my code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)

ukmap = gpd.read_file("..\\gb_1km.shp")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ukmap.plot(ax=ax) #check map
geo_df.plot(ax=ax, markersize=20, color='blue', marker = 'o', label = 'C')
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

Without the background shapefile the plot of the geometry looks like this:

[image]

Why is this happening and how could I fix it? Thanks

**EDIT: With epsg = 27700**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that the `crs` of `geo_df` and `ukmap` are the same? Based on your plots, it appears that they may not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering in a bit more detail as this seems clear enough...

In your code generating `geo_df`, you specify a `crs` of `'epsg:4326'`, and based on your code, you are working in degree latitudes and longitudes. This is confirmed by looking at [EPSG 4326](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/), which specifies the bounds of the CRS as [-180, -90, 180, 90].

I downloaded and read in the file you linked. This code:

```
uk_10km = gpd.read_file(r'/Users/brendancox/Downloads/Great_Britain_shapefile/gb_10km.shp')
uk_10km.crs
```

returns

```
{'init': 'epsg:3035'}
```

[EPSG 3035](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-etrs-laea/) indicates that its units are in metres. The **WGS84 bounds** are [-10.6700, 34.5000, 31.5500, 71.0500], but the **projected bounds** are [2426378.0132, 1528101.2618, 6293974.6215, 5446513.5222].

Thus when you plot `geo_df` onto the UK shapefile, it aligns to the `ukmap` `crs`, placing it in the bottom corner.

Given that EPSG 4326 is for the entire globe, and you are focusing on the UK, I would recommend using a UK-specific projection. EPSG 3035 appears to be for all of Europe, so you could probably find a UK-specific projection into which to convert both of your shape files, using `geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs()`.

## Reproducible example

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
world.to_crs(epsg='3035', inplace=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
world.plot(ax=ax)
cities.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: Reproducible example map]

This shows how re-projecting the built-in `world` shape to EPSG 3035 increases the scale, and makes the `cities` shape appear in a small cluster near (0, 0) -- in this case, at the center of the map.

Comment: EPSG:27700 is the prefered GB projection

Comment: Thanks for your replies and comments. Using epsg = 27700 for UK, some progress as shown in 3rd chart in OP - the UK shapefile is now centred but the Point objects are still crunched to a single point. I suspect this is because the co-ordinates are not aligned yet. Second graphic, OP, axes run b/w -8 and 0 (X), 50 to 58 (Y) while thrid graphic, OP, axes run b/w -250000 and 750000 (X), -250000 to 150000 (Y). Any ideas how to sync them?

Comment: @shanlodh It looks like the same issue: due to different coordinate systems, the point objects are all clustered around (0,0), while the overall UK shape is plotted against larger values. Have you converted *both* shape files to the same CRS? If you haven't already, read through the geopandas page [Managing Projections](http://geopandas.org/projections.html).

Comment: Yes, I did the following and checked the crs: 

`geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs={'init': 'epsg:27700'}, geometry=geometry)
geo_df.crs #prints {'init': 'epsg:27700'}`

Yet the output remains unchanged from fig 3 in OP. I also notice that the values in the type(Point) column in geo_df do not change and I think we want these to be within the range of the UK shapefile axes values?

Comment: Not 100% certain and posting without access to Python, but I think the issue here may be that your `geo_df` is *not* in `epsg=27700` coordinates, but rather in lat-lon coordinates. You need to define `geo_df` with a lat-lon CRS matching the input points, and then use `.to_crs()` (with `inplace=True` perhaps) to *re-project* into `epsg=27700`. See the link in the previous comment as well.

Comment: @BrendanCox Thanks for persevering with me, it's working now. The missing bit was in your link above: "For example, if you convert a **spreadsheet of latitudes and longitudes** into a GeoSeries by hand, you would set the projection by assigning the WGS84 latitude-longitude CRS to the crs attribute:

`my_geoseries.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}`"

So, in summary: 
`geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}, geometry=geometry) 
geo_df.to_crs({'init':'epsg:27700'}, inplace=True)`. Only problem is that its taking almost 7 minutes to run, will look into. Thanks again

Comment: Glad you've got it working. Re: speed: You may want to try using a less detailed shape file while getting the code working, and then switching to a more detailed shape file when everything else is sorted. E.g., the 10km shape file from your link is ~200 kb, while the 1km shape file is ~19 MB -- using the 10km file should speed up your code significantly, I would think, but it may also depend on how much information is in your `geo_df` dataframe.